# Notification when my document is opened

Tags: windows-7, server

I'm working under windows 7 among a group persons(every one has his own PC). We have a shared server containing our documents.

What I would like is to be notified every time a document of mine is opened by another person or at least to have the history of persons who have opened the document with corresponding dates.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't have its own built in Monitoring tool.
So you either have to install a Monitoring tool.  The one I am recommending is

> 1. NetShareMonitor
> 2. ShareMonitor

or you can just create a document management system to control access and sharing to your docs. You can use something like SharePoint or Alfresco, etc

I hope this helps